# Throw exception instead of return in Java method

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm writing `Deque` class on Java, according to [Algorithms, Part 1](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI) on Coursera. And currently my array-based `Deque` has method `removeLast()`:

```
public Item removeLast() {
    if (size() == array.length / 4) {
        resize(array.length / 2);
    }

    if (head != tail) {
        Item tmp = array[--head];
        array[head] = null;
        return tmp;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
}
```

If  `head == tail` means `Deque` is empty and I throw exception, according to homework specification, at the end of method instead of `return`  statement. This code gives direct intention about invariants (`head != tail`).

On the other hand method may be rewritten like this:

```
public Item removeLastRewritten() {
    if (size() == array.length / 4) {
        resize(array.length / 2);
    }

    if (head == tail) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
    }

    Item tmp = array[--head];
    array[head] = null;
    return tmp;
}
```

In my opinion `removeLast` is more clearly written by these reasons:

1. Adhere to pessimistic scenario - `always fail, only if ...` which is more reliable approach, especially when method code will enlarge and become more complicated.
2. Gives more clear link between invariant `tail != head` and subsequent `if {}` code block.

**I have the following questions:**

1. Which is a better approach?
2. Is it considered an appropriate/good practice to write like `removeLast`?
3. What is considered a best practice for Java? Is there any code style about it (I couldn't find any)?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a wrong answer. In GrepCode you can find every flavour you propose:

1. Inside a if with the *!=* operator and at the end of the method:

[E java.util.PriorityQueue.next()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#PriorityQueue.Itr.next%28%29)

```
public E More ...next() {
    if (... != ...)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    ...
    if (...) {
        return lastRetElt;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

2. Inside a if with the *==* operator

[E org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentList.first()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.fluentlenium/fluentlenium-core/0.5.6/org/fluentlenium/core/domain/FluentList.java#FluentList.first%28%29)

```
public E More ...first() {
    if (this.size() == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Element not found");
    }
    return this.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Good point that `throw Exception` instead of `return` even is used in `java.util.PriorityQueue` in some cases!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it looks weird is because you omit the `else` block of your `if` block, which would incorporate either leftover that comes after the `if` block in both your methods. The reason you can get away with it here is because the thrown exception will disrupt the flow of your method.

I think it's better not to rely on that and just be nice and use the `if-else` blocks intuitively.

```
public Item removeLastRewrittenAgain() {
    if (size() == array.length / 4) {
        resize(array.length / 2);
    }

    if (head != tail) { // invert the if-else block if preferred, it would not make any difference
        Item tmp = array[--head];
        array[head] = null;
        return tmp;
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
    }
}
```

Another reason why I don't really like to throw exceptions before the end of a method is that I strongly believe in and thus thoroughly use the concept of `a single point of exit`, meaning I don't leave the method somewhere in the middle which I believe is more difficult to read for someone not familiar with the code.

One place to return your value (or thrown exceptions): the very bottom of your method.

Comment: `a signle point of exit` is appropriate and have reasons only when you have one `kind of return value`. Throwing exception is another kind. For example, when you write function which return `Integer` and **doesn't** return any kind of exception you might use `one return statement`. In another cases it is not possible.

Comment: Thus neither upper `removeLast`, nor bottom `removeLastRewritten` can't use one return statement. For `removeLastRewritten` exception in middle of method is the same as `return` at the point.

Comment: Indeed so that exceptions are the 'exception' (pun not intended) to the rule, but I tend to collect the state of validity of the arguments or local variables in a (bunch of) local boolean(s), that I then use at the end to decide whether to return my value or throw an exception instead. Maybe I'm going too far by doing that, but I like it that way personally.

Answer (score 1):

Your code becomes more readable if you explicitly mention the `else`, regardless of your choice.

Then there is the dilemma of

```
if (head != tail) {
    Item tmp = array[--head];
    array[head] = null;
    return tmp;
} else {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
}
```

versus

```
if (head == tail) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
} else {
    Item tmp = array[--head];
    array[head] = null;
    return tmp;
}
```

Here I strongly prefer the second one. When I'm reading the "complicated part" of the if statement, I want to know why I'm actually inside an `if`. When reading the first variant the whole reason for the if only becomes apparent when you're throwing the exception.

I guess you could also solve that by writing

```
boolean isEmpty = head == tail;
if (!isEmpty) {
    Item tmp = array[--head];
    array[head] = null;
    return tmp;
}
throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
```

but I prefer the version that throws the exception as soon as you know something is wrong.